# JavaScript library to develop a flowchart simulator in HTML

Tags: javascript, flowchart

I want to develop a [flowchart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) simulator where a user can do flowcharts for programs and things like that. I came across the GoJS library in this regard, but it looks like there's a licensing issue with it as I am getting this message:

> Go JS evaluation- Not for distribution or production. Use nwoods.com.

What is the best library for having my work done?

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/adrai/flowchart.js or raphael.js

Answer (score 1):

I wrote code for [diagramo](http://diagramo.com), so I can tell you that it is [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5)-based and free. Give it a try; it might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You may mean something like the *[Logic Circuit](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/logicCircuit.html)* sample, which does a very simple emulation of an electronic circuit.

GoJS is a commercial library, so you need to acquire a license. But free licenses [are available for academic use](http://www.nwoods.com/sales/academic-use.html).